# Render Translucent/Transparent Overlay

Tags: c#, .net, overlay, .net-2.0, gdi+

I need a fast way to draw an overlay on a screen with transparency support. I've done a lot of searching and found one potential solution (which has its own problems) and another solution that does not fit my requirements; specifically transparency support.

I'll start with the latter and then touch on the former.

---

### Solution 1

Using a borderless form with a TransparencyKey, this is one of the most recommended solutions I've found and the least helpful.

This solution works by having a new Form, have it borderless, set the background to something like `Colour.White` and set the `TransparencyKey` to the same colour, have it be fullscreen and topmost, and maybe set some other options to have it act invisible to the mouse and keyboard.

The problem with this solution is that it does not support transparency; it will only 'knock out' colours *exactly the same* as the `TransparencyKey` and as such anything with even the slightest difference will be shown throwing the idea of having translucent objects on the screen out the window.

---

### Solution 2

Use P/Invoke and GDI+ to get (`GetDC` & `Graphics.FromHdc`), actually draw to, and then release (`ReleaseDC`) the desktop.

For what it does it works quite well, unfortunately however there are some problems.

First of all; calling it once will quite obviously only draw it once and as such if the screen refreshes at all after being drawn it will disappear, I do not understand how to fix this and if this is the best solution I'll most definitely need help with this issue.

Second of all; GDI+ is insanely slow with this method using a translucent Brush and `FillRectangle` and I honestly can't blame it, however I require it to be done quite fast; a requirement which GDI+ apparently cannot fufill.

---

In conclusion; I require a method of drawing an overlay over a screen that has transparency support, if the second method is the method I should be using how can I draw with a translucent brush fast enough that it's not a problem and how would I have it update so that it wont disappear after the screen refreshes, and if it's not the method I should be using please specify what method I *should* be using.

Comment: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/288007/create-transparent-overlay-on-desktop

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/197754/c-transparent-image-overlay

Comment: what about using WPF?

Comment: @WeylandYutani How do you mean? I have a fairly basic understanding of WPF.

Comment: WPF is another way of doing Solution 1 (fullscreen window, topmost, etc) but unlike winforms you can use an alpha component for the window background to make it fully or partially transparent. This link is very old but shows what can be done http://laurenlavoie.com/avalon/148. Also you should be able to draw sprites not just a flat single color background (I haven't done this though)

Comment: @WeylandYutani I don't think I'll be able to use WPF in this specific situation due how my program works (it's not that it couldn't be done in WPF, it's that my project depends on this being a WinForm).

Comment: Whoops, I didn't mean "Depends on this being a WinForm"; I meant "Depends on this not being WPF".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is not in your list. Solution #3 is to use UpdateLayeredWindow with a bitmap with an alpha channel. When updating the bitmap, you must paint only the areas that need updating, and use the fastest bitmap format (pre-multiplied ARBG). Here is an example of some graphics I created using solution #2, which seems fast enough: [Translucent clock and calculator](http://www.vgdotnet.com/articles/translucent_calculator.shtml)

Here are some more details. We have a class called GdiBuffer, containing a GDI handle field and a DC handle field (both encapsulated in classes, GdiHandle and DCHandle). It is initialized in the following way:

```
    public GdiBitmap(int width, int height)
    {
        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height))
            Initialize(bitmap);
    }
private void Initialize(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        _size = bitmap.Size;
        _handle = new GdiHandle(bitmap.GetHbitmap(), true);
        _deviceContext = UnsafeNativeMethods.CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr.Zero);
        UnsafeNativeMethods.SelectObject(_deviceContext, _handle);
    }
```

The Bitmap is a GDI+ bitmap. This means we _deviceContext is now representing both the GDI+ bitmap, and something we can use in GDI.

When it is time to update the screen, we pass a Form into the method in GdiBuffer that can update the screen:

```
            if (!form.Visible)
            return false;
        IntPtr formHandle = form.Handle;
        if (formHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            return false;
        Check.Argument(opacity >= 0 && opacity <= 1, "opacity");
        // the future bounds was stored if the TranslucentForm Bounds property
        // changed at any time. the true update to the window bounds only
        // happens here, in the UpdateLayeredWindow call
        bool futureBoundsSet = form.FutureBoundsSet;
        Rect bounds = form.GetFutureBounds();
        SIZE newSize = new SIZE(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
        POINT newPosition = new POINT(bounds.Left, bounds.Top);
        POINT pointSource = new POINT();
        BLENDFUNCTION blend = new BLENDFUNCTION((byte)(opacity * 255));
        IntPtr screenDC = UnsafeNativeMethods.GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);

        bool result;
        try
        {
            result = UnsafeNativeMethods.UpdateLayeredWindow(formHandle, screenDC, ref newPosition,
                ref newSize, _deviceContext, ref pointSource, 0, ref blend, UnsafeNativeMethods.ULW_ALPHA);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (screenDC != IntPtr.Zero)
                UnsafeNativeMethods.ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, screenDC);
        }
```

To use our GdiBuffer internally:

```
_gdiBuffer = new GdiBitmap(_bufferSize);
_graphics = Graphics.FromHdc(_gdiBuffer.DeviceContext.DangerousGetHandle());
```

The _graphics field is where we actually draw.

Comment: A translucent Brush will cover anywhere from 100% of the screen to 1%, I need to account for the former.

Comment: You need double buffering. It is built in with that type of window, as you need a bitmap to update the screen anyway. So you are rendering to a bitmap. Translucent brushes are super fast for me so I cannot say where the problem is.

Comment: If you give me a basic example of what you want I can verify if the performance is an issue in a test application -- this type of thing is simple with the TranslucentForm class.

Comment: @AlphaDelta: Sorry, I completely misunderstood your solution #2. The method you propose will be slow regardless of what you are drawing. The best solution (and the one we use) is another one, solution #3. I tried to describe it as best I could in my edited answer. It is a difficult problem and I left out all the details about form sizing, resource management, and disposal. You need to be quite good in both GDI+ and GDI to understand this, but I hope it helps.

Comment: It was a while back but I did something similar myself. The problem I hit was that a semi-transparent pixel (eg 10% grey) would get progressively darker on each subsequent paint. Are you re-creating the bitmap every time? If not, how are you avoiding the same issue?

Comment: @Basic: No I am not creating a new bitmap every time. I am just erasing parts and redrawing those parts each time. Only the parts that are animated are erased and redrawn. That is handled automatically by the vector graphics system we use (VG.net). In your case, it sounds like you are erasing using a brush that is transparent. That is the expected result. We did something similar with our particle system simulation, where we wanted to have "trails" after each particle. 10K particles. In that case, the particle system had its own transparent Bitmap buffer, as an overlay.

Comment: @Basic: you have to erase using a brush that does erasure (replace operation) but leaves the pixels transparent. I would have to look up the exact operation we use, but I think it is Bitmap.Clear, with a transparent color, and a clipping region.