# c# WinForms: Make part of the Form transparent

Tags: c#, winforms, opacity, transparent

I have `Form1` which contains has background image with error message and with some buttons and shows up when some error happens. I have to make part of the `Form1` transparent while the other part will contain an error message and it will be nontransparent. Here's some illustration.

[image]

The grey part of the `Form1` must be say, 80% transparent. How can I achieve it?

So far I've tried to play with `Opacity`but it makes the whole frame transparent. Please help me out of this I really need to make this today, Thanks a lot.

Comment: how are you displaying the error message (with what control)

Comment: Thanks for reminding. I add a background image on my `Form1` , the image contains error code. I guess it makes task more complicated.

Comment: You may want to search for `semi-transparent c# form`, once you know that - you can solve your task. The first result is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13036218/1997232).

Comment: You can always workaround by having two forms, One semitransparent (Opacity=0.7f) the other centered above it. Synch the movable outer one with the other, titleless one in its move event

Comment: You are looking for the `UpdateLayeredWindow` function. It isn't going to be easy to make this work from WinForms. You'll be writing a lot of P/Invoke code, and judging from the way you asked this question, you're in well over your head. Do keep in mind that this kind of transparency rarely serves a useful function. The image you showed is making my eyes hurt.

Comment: I showed image to make people understand better what I needed, not to satisfy your eyes ;)

Comment: Related: [Render Translucent/Transparent Overlay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24261902/render-translucent-transparent-overlay) and [Splash-screen with alpha channels transparency/opacity in WinForms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851738/splash-screen-with-alpha-channels-transparency-opacity-in-winforms)

Answer (score 1):

set BackColor and TransparencyKey same color

Comment: Thanks. But this is not what I wanted. It makes the grey part of the form fully transparent. I want to make it transparent 70-80% . In other words I want to set opacity of this part to 70-80%